# Grep words with exact two vowels

Tags: grep, aix

I have the following issue, I need to retrieve all words that contains exactly 2 vowels (in any order) from a file. The file only contains one word per line.

My current workaround is:

**Grep1:** Retrieve words such as `earth, over, under, one...`

```
 grep -i "^[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$" genesis.words  > A.txt
```

and

**Grep2:** Retrieve words such as `formless, deep, said...`

```
 grep -i "^[^aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$" genesis.words > B.txt
```

the above solution works but when I concatenate both regexs into a single regex then return nothing!

**Mother of Grep1 & Grep2:** should retrieve everything!

```
 grep -i "^[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$|^[^aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$" genesis.words
```

I think issue is around my implementation of `^$` in expression but have tried diff versions with no sucess!

Any help will be highly appreciated!

OS is AIX 6100-09-04-1441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. This should work:

```
grep -i "^[^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$" genesis.words  > A.txt
```

So it should find all eight possibilities (two vowels identify three nonvowel sequence, each possibly empty; 2^3 is 8):

```
     [ ]I[ ]o[ ]
     [ ]e[ ]a[r]
     [ ]e[r]a[ ]
     [ ]e[l]a[n]
     [T]e[ ]a[ ]
     [D]e[ ]a[r]
     [D]e[w]a[r]
     [D]a[w]a[ ]
     [H]a[w]a[y]
```

As for concatenation, | needs escaping. You can use a single anchoring:

```
 ^(regexp1\|regexp2)$
```

Comment: thanks! your solution works like a charm! as for the concatenation I applied your suggestion but still return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `*` can match 0 times or more you should be able to start the string with `[^aeiou]*`: try

```
"^[^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$"
```

As for fixing your regex, I think you need to escape the bar as `\|`, so

```
grep -i "^[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$\|^[^aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$" genesis.words
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind `Perl`, you could use this:

```
perl -lne '$m=$_; tr/[aeiou]//cd; print $m if length()==2;' /usr/share/dict/words
```

That says... *"save the current line (word) in $m. Delete everything that is not a vowel. Print the original word if there are two things (i.e vowels) left."*

Note that I am using the system dictionary as input for my tests.

You could do pretty much the same thing in `awk`.

Comment: This shows why `Perl` is at times such an awesome language! +1 You mentioned `awk`, although is there any advantage using one over the other?

Comment: I guess, to me at least, the advantage of Perl is that it is exactly the same across Linux, Unix, OSX, Windows - just one standard regex syntax, just one consistent file naming convention, one standardised set of line endings, one set of escapes, just one date syntax, just one `find` syntax, it does all that `tr` can do, `sed`, all that `awk` can do, `grep`, `fgrep`, CPAN...

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use an alternative to grep `tr` with `wc` works well:

```
words=/path/to/words.txt

while read -e word ; do
    v=$(echo $word | tr -cd 'aeiou' | wc -c)
    [[ ! $v -eq "2" ]] || echo $word >> output.txt 
done < $words
```

This reads the original file line by line, counts the vowels & returns results with only 2 to output.txt.

Comment: thanks for diff approach - haven't thought this way however since this is normally run from command line (quick & dirty) grep would be best option in this specific case.